# Advice on how to attack my first reverse engineering project?

Tags: hardware, communication, physical-attacks

Suppose you've never done reverse engineering before (apart from taking apart already-broken tape recorders). Also suppose you had a machine as pictured below, with a serial-looking and another multi-pin connector on the back. Thirdly, suppose you wanted to use this console as a computer input, hoping to gain control of more than just the keyboard part (it's got a trackball, a hefty jog/cue wheel, rotary dials, blinkenlights, and a two-line character VFD display).

Lastly, suppose you *don't* have access to any technical specifications! No user manual, no installation guide, no service manual, not even a crappy nth-generation photocopy of the pin-outs. The company no longer exists, and the archive of their web site is of no help. Pretty much all I have is that this console runs on "90-264V" and draws "<42W".

On the plus side, I (used to) know the operation of this console very well. For instance, I can tell you it's got no real brains -- *that* is in a separate computer, *this* is merely the controller for it. The main computer costs thousands, and anyway is purpose-built and not useful as a general computing device (I don't think this runs a regular operating system "behind the scenes", at least I could recognize no tell-tale signs from the boot sequence, file system naming, or something like that).

I am confident that I could surely figure out the main power pins based on the red and black wires going to that Molex connector ... but the rest of those pins? All that functionality? I don't even know where to start.

I am a programmer by trade, I'm pretty good with my hands, including competency with a soldering iron and a multimeter. I don't have (access to) an oscilloscope, signal analyzer, or any such fanciness.

A few hints for me? Is this even doable?

[image: Accom Axial editing console]
[image: connectors on the back]
[image: back side off mode]

**EDIT:** By the way, these are the chassis: The Display chassis on top of the Comms chassis (neither of which I have, or plan to acquire).

[image: Display and Comms chassis]

Comment: If it really was connected to some old computer, people over at retrocomputing SE should be able to help with info.

Comment: Good idea, although I don't think it's old _enough_ to be retro in that sense.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It was made by humans so there's a spec.

[image]

I googled it.

Here's [a manual which talks about the Axial MX from Accom ~2005](https://usermanual.wiki/Document/AxialMXInstallGuide.392315378/view). If it's a series of edit controllers, they'll likely work the same under the hood and use the same protocol from one version to the next.

[image: Ports]

Looks like an RS422 Serial. So you just need to hook it up to a computer with a serial port and take a look at what data is transmitted when you hit a key. You'll have to [figure out some of the serial port parameters such as rate, parity, etc,](https://github.com/devttys0/baudrate/blob/master/baudrate.py) but this should get you going.

[image]

Comment: I bow in respect of your awesome google-fu. I tried all sorts of keywords, but that there is good!

Comment: Ah, so basically it's an RS422 serial connection. I know nothing about it, but that can be learned.

Comment: You might look at this: https://github.com/devttys0/baudrate/blob/master/baudrate.py

Comment: It's an edit controller with RS-422 running over a DE-9, so that's probably a [Sony 9-Pin (A.K.A. P1) Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9-Pin_Protocol) connector. The pinout chart appears to match up. According to the linked Wikipedia article, "The communication parameters are 38,400 baud, 8 data bits, odd parity and 1 stop bit (38k4/8O1)." It links to this [protocol description](ftp://ftp.jurassic.nl/mirrors/ftp.sgi.com/sgi/video/rld/vidpage/s9pinnt.html).

Comment: Great find @ssoklow! I found a similar PDF describing the protocol (http://ffv.com/pdf/Recon-4-Serial-Control-Protocol.pdf)

Comment: @pythonpython - I will definitely read up on all those files. Such professional header and footer in that last PDF! ;-D

Comment: @pythonpython could we know what was the search query? I'm also amazed by your skills :D